# Invalid Token 401 when I try to create or auto generate customer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm super new to React and Redux toolkit. When I try to create or autogenerate a customer I get an unauthorized error 401, Invalid token. But I don't get the error when Get all customers. When I check application I can see the token there. What could I be doing wrong please? It works on localhost but doesn't when I deploy to Render.

[image]

```js
const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
const { token } = user || {};

//Create new customer
const createCustomer = async (customerData) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  };
  const response = await axios.post(
    `${PROD}/api/v1/customer/create-customers`,
    customerData,
    config
  );

  return response.data;
};

const autoGenerate = async (generate_customers) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  };
  const response = await axios.post(
    `${PROD}/api/v1/customer/generate-customers`,
    generate_customers,
    config
  );
  return response.data;
};

const getAllCustomers = async (token) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  };
  const response = await axios.get(
    `${PROD}/api/v1/customer/paginate-customer`,
    config
  );
  return response.data;
};

const customerService = {
  createCustomer,
  autoGenerate,
  getAllCustomers,
};

export default customerService;
```

```js
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import customerService from "./customerService";

const initialState = {
  customer: [],
  customers: [],
  isLoading: true,
  isError: false,
  isSuccess: false,
  message: "",
};

// Create new customer
export const createCustomer = createAsyncThunk(
  "customer/createCustomer",
  async (customer, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token;
      return await customerService.createCustomer(customer, token);
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        (error.response &&
          error.response.data &&
          error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString();
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
  }
);

// Generate new customer
export const autoGenerate = createAsyncThunk(
  "customer/autoGenerate",
  async (generate_customer, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token;
      return await customerService.autoGenerate(generate_customer, token);
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        (error.response &&
          error.response.data &&
          error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString();
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
  }
);

// Get all customers
export const getAllCustomers = createAsyncThunk(
  "customer/getAllCustomers",
  async (_, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token;
      return await customerService.getAllCustomers(token);
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        (error.response &&
          error.response.data &&
          error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString();
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
  }
);
```